# Блок не показывается на всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css

Прописал в .css файле widht: 100%, но на сайте имеются отступы в 5 пикселей с обеих сторон, как исправить и что я сделал не так? [image: Скриншот страницы]

```
HTML: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CS:GO News & Coverage | HLTV.org</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="800x800" href="hltv.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HLTV.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#1B1F23">
    <nav class="nav">
        
    </nav>
        <img src="news-banner.png" class="news-banner" height="180">
        <div class="glow">
            fajfpafpajgpjka
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {

}

.news-banner {
    margin-left: 640px;
    margin-top: 132px;
}

.glow:hover {
    color: #708191;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
```

Речь идет про блок наверху сайта, понятное дело

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

А ширину можно вообще выкинуть.